# c# displaying something in a listbox through a button based on info in a textbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am working on a Security Panel in c# on visual studio and I'm having trouble how to display something in a listbox by clicking on a button based on something placed in a textbox.

I know how to display whatever is in the textbox to a listbox, but I would like to display something else in the listbox.

For example, the code "1432" is entered by clicking the button # (btnHASH) and in the listbox "Security team" is displayed

```
            if (codeTXT.Text == "1432")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("INFO First Year Students");
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "2543")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("INFO Second Year Students");
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "3543")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("B.Tech Students");
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "2645")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("CSIT Faculty");
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "2646")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("CSIT Faculty");
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "2647")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("CSIT Faculty");
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "2648")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("CSIT Faculty");
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "8888")
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add("IET Staff");
```

The output in the listbox needs Date, Time and then the message.

Comment: try  `(codeTXt.Text == "whatever")`

Comment: I missed something in the information, the date and time of the user entering through the panel and then the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need == not = in if statements.

Example:

```
if (codeTXT.Text == "1432")
```

You can use the DateTime.Now to get the current date and time. Then convert to string and add them.

Comment: how would I add it into the statement? I'm fairly confused with that

Comment: Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now) + "1432";

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is like following code in your Click Button event:

```
switch(codeTXT.Text)
{
    case "1432":
        accessboxLIST.Items.Add(String.Format("[{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss}]INFO First Year Students", DateTime.Now));
        break;
    case "2543":
        accessboxLIST.Items.Add(String.Format("[{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss}]INFO Second Year Students", DateTime.Now));
        break;
    //Your other cases like that.
}
```